# Modifying code during runtime in Visual Studio Code C++ MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, runtime, mingw

I've recently switched from VS to VSCode. In VS I can edit source code during runtime and these changes will be applied in the runtime. How can I do this in *VSCode* with *C++ MinGW*? Or my compiler can't do that?

Comment: "Edit and continue" for c++ is a Visual Studio feature and it works only with vc++ compiler.